# Question on restriction of irreducible group representations to normal subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I am confused about the answers to the following question:
[Restriction to a normal subgroup](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/43004/restriction-to-a-normal-subgroup)

with the original question copied here:

> Let $A$ be a normal subgroup of a finite group $G$ and $V$ an irreducible representation of $G$. Show that either $\text{Res}_A^G V$ is isotypic (a sum of copies of one irreducible representation of $A$) or that $V$ is induced from some proper subgroup of $G$.

I came across the same question in Lang's Algebra, however, Lang does not talk about torsion groups in the section nor is there mention of Clifford's theorem. Therefore, I was wondering if there was another, perhaps more fundamental, way to approach this question, as both answers are based off of other results.

Comment: I would say this is just a reformulation of Clifford's Theorem, which is more or less what Geoff Robinson said in his previous answer to the question.